# Улучшить точность при расчетах с числами после точки

Tags: python, double

Есть программа для расчета сопротивления в схеме с `n` количеством звеньев. Есть код с рекурсией (важно сделать именно рекурсию, такова моя задача), в котором примерно после 16 звеньев python просто перестает считать и выводит одинаковые числа при любом значении `n`. Как сделать так чтобы программа выводила мне точные числа (если это вообще возможно)?

```
def Rx(r):
    if r == 1:
        return 3
    res = Rx(r - 1)
    return 2 + res/(1+res)

a=int(input())
print(Rx(a))
```

Comment: Код неправильно форматирован. И почему вы думаете, что числа неточные? Какой результат должен быть для 20, например?

Comment: Вы осознали, что я вам в прошлой ветке писал про достижение предела точности double? Я почему спрашиваю - какой предполагается результат, скажем, для n=30, 1000, 30000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь использовать встроенный в python модуль decimal
`from decimal import Decimal Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.2")  # 0.3`
Тем самым исправив проблемы с точностью, потом уже сможешь округлить до нужного количества знаков. *Примечание: в Dicimal передаётся строка, а не число, а так же нельзя смешивать в операциях дробные числа float и Decimal (т.е. сначала нужно всё привести к Decimal)

Comment: Спасибо! Все отлично заработало!